# How to use fetch with datamuse API and react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to javascript and react and I am trying to use an API to get words that are related to "dog", but I am getting "TypeError: Unable to get property 'NaN' of undefined or null reference" whenever I try and access the random word part. I think I am not accessing the information provided by datamuse but I really don't know how else to change the code to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
//import words from './words'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const words = [];
        this.state={
            words,
            guessedLetters: [],
            guessesRemaining: 6
        };
        this.getWord()
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        const {words} = prevState
        return {word: words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words)]} // chooses random word

    }

    getWord() {
        fetch("https://api.datamuse.com/words?ml=dogs")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    words: result.words
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    error
                });
            }
        )
    console.log(this.state.words)
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="App">
        <h1>Hangman</h1>
        {this.state.words}
        {this.state.word}
        </div>
        );
    }
}



export default App;
```

Comment: well ... where **is** it defined?

Comment: Looks like the author is very new and he thinks that it is defined on the previous line.  Few years ago I also was the same :)

Comment: she* so where do I define it at?

Answer (score 0):

You have no `words` variable in your constructor.

You may resolve this problem in a next manner:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const words = [];
    this.state={
        words,
        word: words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)], //chooses random word
        guessedLetters: [],
        guessesRemaining: 6
    };
}
```

But as I see you will have a problem because that code runs only once and `word` won't be updated after state update.

To resolve this problem you may use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)` method in next manner

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        words: [],
        guessedLetters: [],
        guessesRemaining: 6
    };
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const {words} = prevState
    return {word: words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]} // chooses random word
}
```

And even better solution with state definition, suggested by Ravi Malviya

```
state = {
  words: [],
  guessedLetters: [],
  guessesRemaining: 6
};

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const {words} = prevState
    return {word: words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]} // chooses random word
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error that "words" is not defined when I try to compute the random part.

Comment: There were missed init value in state

Answer (score -1):

First of all its seem that you are initializing your state in constructor as well as outside of this, like

```
state = {
...
}
```

Note :- This is an alternate way to initialize your state, so it is internally convert into constructor() .

So there is no any 'words' during state initialization.